# ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader Caused by:IllegalStateException: Stream is already initialized. Close before re-opening

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've repeated the example provided in the [Creating a Batch Service tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)

But I want to add second step to the job so it should do following:

1 step(it is already provided in tutorial): read people names from csv and save it in databse in upperCase

2 step: read from database names convert it to lowercase and insert into another database table.

Currently my configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    // tag::readerwriterprocessor[]
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("users.csv"))
                .delimited()
                .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                    setTargetType(Person.class);
                }})
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> dbReader(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person> personBeanWrapperFieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }};
        reader.setRowMapper(new RowMapper<Person>() {
            @Override
            public Person mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
                Person person = new Person();
                person.setFirstName(resultSet.getString(0));
                person.setLastName(resultSet.getString(1));
                return person;
            }
        });
        reader.setSql("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM people");
        reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ToLowerCaseProcessor processor2() {
        return new ToLowerCaseProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)")
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .build();
    }
    // end::readerwriterprocessor[]

    // tag::jobstep[]
    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1, Step step2) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                //.incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .listener(new JobExecutionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!SECOND_LISTENER_BEFORE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!SECOND_LISTENER_AFTER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    }
                })
                .flow(step1)
                .next(step2)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer, DataSource dataSource) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                .reader(dbReader(dataSource))
                .processor(processor2())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
    // end::jobstep[]
}
```

But when I start my spring boot application on the second step I experince the following error:

```
2019-08-02 14:33:54.164 ERROR 26972 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step step2 in job importUserJob

org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:152) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:206) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:180) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:167) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:162) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream is already initialized.  Close before re-opening.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:424) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:149) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

I have no idea what do I wrong. What the stream has mentioned ?
Could please explain how to correct it ?

Answer (score 1):

in your dbReader method you should'nt call :

```
reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
```

It is called by springbatch.